# Macbook Air 2015 High Sierra cannot merge free space partitions

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

[image: in my disk utility]
[image: when i select the 'minus' sign for free space and bc1]
[image: this pops up when i try to delete the free space and bc1]
[image: diskutil list]
I think I messed everything up when I erased the content of a partition from bootcamp.  Please give simple instructions.  I have no knowledge about how storages work.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The simple fix is:

1. Back everything up (apps and files and settings and possibly keychain passwords if you don’t have them written down / recorded elsewhere)
2. Boot to internet recovery
3. Erase and start with one partition

Using the command line to merging containers requires you to clearly understand quite a few items and processes and concepts and one mistake ruins the data. It’s like several passes on a trapeze at the circus, without a net. It takes months of experience to make it look effortless and years of experience to always succeed.

Here’s your guide to easy and the site will be here as you gain storage knowledge.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065

Comment: Thanks for your help. I backed up everything to a hard disk, cleared my whole mac, updated it to mojave and restored everything.  Now everything's fine.